# MultiStore with Independent Admin

Tags: magento2, module, admin, multistore, login

I would like to know if there is a way, maybe some module, that allows me to have Magento 2 installation with several stores where each store has an independent Admin Login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in Magento EE.

Module calls Magento/AdminGws

AdminGws provides configuration management within the Global, Website, and Store data scopes. Restrictions can be imposed on various system elements through configurations that are applied at the desired level.